# Scanning string from byte array

Tags: c, scanf

Is there a way to use `scanf()` to scan a string from an array of bytes?

i.e: scan any number of bytes before a specific value is found, and after that scan the subsequent string?

The main problem I'm having is dealing with the `'\0'` value. Is there a way to make `scanf()` bypass the `NUL` terminator in a controlled way?

Comment: Scanf is only for scanning zero terminated strings. So non you cannot skip the zero terminator. Please explain what you want to do exactly.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you tried ? Or some example of input, and expected output?

Comment: @Michael Walz `scanf()`, scanning from `stdin`, _can_ scan though `'\0'` using `scanf("%[^\n]", buf)`.  This will take in input and save until a `'\n'` is reached, including a `'\0'`.  Once a `'\n'` occurs, scanning stops (`'\n'` is put back into `stdin`) and a `'\0'` is appended to `buf`.  Had a `'\0'` been scanned, using `strlen(buf)` gives a reduced result.  Using `scanf("%[^\n]%n", buf, &n)`, code could determine the length scanned.  It _is_ unusual to see a `'\0'` in `stdin`.

Comment: @chux: I agree "it is unusual to see a '\0' in stdin". But it is easy enough to generate, even accidentally: a control-@ `^@` on the keyboard will on many Unix systems give a `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just iterate over the string?

```
char str[30];
char str1[30];
char str2[30];
//Initialize str it to some string

int i=0;

while(str[i]!='x') //say scan till you find x
{
    i++;
}
i++;
memcpy(str1, str, i); //extract this substring till x
str1[i+1]='\0';

int j=0;
while(str[i]!='\0') //now copy the rest
{
    j++; //track the  point where x appeared
    i++;
}

memcpy(str2, &str[i-j], j); //extract the rest
str2[j+1]='\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sscanf()` instead:

```
 char string[100] = "720 11 43";
 int x, y, z;

 sscanf(string, "%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
```

Comment: Not sure that this is what is being asked.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: One cannot be sure about anything. The question is not very clear. Perhaps she doesn't even know what she really needs. But she is talking about null characters, reading strings and the function scanf(). Let's wait and see if this answer makes happy to **line**.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot do this from an array of bytes using `sscanf()` because `sscanf()` stops when it reaches a `'\0'`. @Joseph Quinsey

If code is reading from a file or `stdin`, there is a solution.

Both `fscanf("%[^something]")` and `fscanf("%c")` will scan a `'\0'`.  Even `fgets()` will scan a `'\0'`.

OP: "scan any number of bytes before a specific value is found, and after that scan the subsequent string?"
The following will 1) scan over any number of byte until an `x` is found, 2) scan the `x`, 3) scan-over white-space and 4) scan and save non-white-space.  Unfortunately this last step treats embedded `'\0'` as non-white-space.

```
ch ch;
char buf[100];
if (1 == fscanf(inf, "%*[^x]x%99s", buf)) string_after_x_is_found(buf);
```

To use `fscanf("%c")` in a general sense

```
FILE *inf;
inf = fopen("something", "rb");   
char ch;
while (fscanf(inf,"%c", &ch) == 1) {
  foo(ch);
}
fclose(inf);
```

Embedded `'\0'` really messes up the `scanf()` family.  Careful use of format *can* work, but I recommend simply using `fread()` or `fgetc()` instead.

Comment: The OP asked to "scan a string from an array of bytes", not from a `FILE *`.

Comment: @Joseph Quinsey I took "scanf() to scan a string from an array of bytes" to imply using the `scanf()` _family_ of functions.  `scanf()` only gets input from `stdin` and so scan a string implies `sscanf()`, which as you rightly implies - is not a FILE and not possiable to scan a `'\0'`.   Both `fscanf()` and `scanf()` can scan `'\0'` with the right directive.  It is tricky though to see a `'\0'` in `stdin` though - usually a pipe.